Video.js HLS video from AWS Cloudfront
Im using AWS CloudFront as a CDN to serve some videos to my site ( Laravel & Vue ). I have set my CloudFront to use signed cookies to get the content from my S3 bucket which looks to be working fine as i can see all my .ts files being fetched in my network tab.
However the issue is when the video plays it crashes around the time it should be switching segments, the error i get is 'The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.'. I can skip to another part of the video and it will play until that segment ends and needs to switch ( this tells me that my site is getting the segments ).
I am also using my site to proxy the cdn, so i make requests to mysite.com/proxyVideo/VideoFileName.m3u8 this signs the request with the cookies and then uses HTTPClient to get the cdn. Below is my Vue component
<template>
    <div>
        <video ref="videoPlayer" id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640"
            height="360">
            <source src="mySite.com/proxyVideo/someplaylist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
        </video>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import videojs from 'video.js';
    import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

    export default {
        mounted() {
            // Initialize Video.js player
            this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, {
                autoplay: true,
                controls: true,
                preload: 'auto',
                techOrder: ['html5'], // Ensure HTML5 is being used
                sources: [{
                    src: 'mySite.com/proxyVideo/someplaylist.m3u8',
                    type: 'application/x-mpegURL' // MIME type for HLS
                }]
            });

            // Wait until the player is ready
            this.player.ready(() => {
                // Directly access the player's tech
                const hlsTech = this.player.tech({
                    IWillNotUseThisInPlugins: true
                });

                if (hlsTech && hlsTech.vhs) {
                    // Extend Video.js XHR to add Range header for .ts files
                    hlsTech.vhs.xhr = (options, callback) => {
                        // Set the Range header if the request is for .ts files
                        if (options.uri.endsWith('.ts')) {
                            options.headers = options.headers || {};
                            options.headers.Range = 'bytes=0-'; // Adjust as needed
                        }

                        // Call the original xhr method
                        return videojs.Vhs.xhr.call(hlsTech.vhs, options, callback);
                    };
                } else {
                    console.error("HLS is not available on this player instance.");
                }
            });
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
            if (this.player) {
                this.player.dispose();
            }
        },
    };
</script>

and here is my Laravel route
Route::any('/proxyVideo/{path}', function(Request $req, $path) {
    $client = new HttpClient();
    
    try {
        // Fetch cookies and format for forwarding
        $cookies = $req->cookies->all();
        $cookieHeader = '';
        foreach ($cookies as $name => $value) {
            $cookieHeader .= "{$name}={$value}; ";
        }
        $cookieHeader = rtrim($cookieHeader, '; ');
        
        $headers =  [
            'Cookie' => $cookieHeader,
            'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes', // Add this to indicate partial support
        ];

        if ($req->hasHeader('Range')) {
            $headers['Range'] = $req->header('Range');
        }

        // Make the request to CloudFront with cookies and headers
        $response = $client->request($req->method(), "cdn.cloudfront.net/{$path}", [
            'headers' => $headers
        ]);

        // Handle response and set status to 206 if Range was requested
        $httpFoundationFactory = new HttpFoundationFactory();
        $symfonyResponse = $httpFoundationFactory->createResponse($response);
        $headers = $symfonyResponse->headers->all();
        $content = $symfonyResponse->getContent();
        $statusCode = $symfonyResponse->getStatusCode();

        // Force 206 if Range is requested but response returns 200
        if ($req->hasHeader('Range') && $statusCode === 200) {
            $statusCode = 206;
        }

        return response($content, $statusCode)
            ->withHeaders($headers)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Range, Content-Type, Authorization')
            ->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length, Content-Range');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unable to proxy request', 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 502);
    }
})->where('path', '.*');

and here is an example of my .m3u8 file
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:10.400000,
video-6724a1ce2ef27.mp4_0_1000_00000.ts
#EXTINF:9.600000,
video-6724a1ce2ef27.mp4_0_1000_00001.ts
#EXTINF:10.400000,
video-6724a1ce2ef27.mp4_0_1000_00002.ts
#EXTINF:1.550000,
video-6724a1ce2ef27.mp4_0_1000_00003.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

if i use a test .m3u8 file from online it does however work. the stream i'm testing with is
https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8
this obviously does not use my proxy so i would guess its something to do with that but not to sure. The .m3u8 file request results in a 200 which i think is correct and the .ts file have 206 which again i think is right


I am also using my site to proxy the cdn

This completely defeats the purpose of the CDN.  The whole point is that clients are supposed to connect directly to it.

// Force 206 if Range is requested but response returns 200


No, don't do this!  Without the associated response headers, your 206 makes no sense to the client.
Don't do any of this.  Stop proxying stuff.  Let your clients connect directly to CloudFront.

Ok, I agree with your point on the CDN. So when I connect to the CDN directly I will still need a signed url or cookies how would you suggest going about this?

@JamesBaker Are you sure?  Your bucket is streaming BBB just fine right now without anything, so your objects are public.  In that case, no signed anything is needed.  If you plan on limiting bucket access later, you'll have to decide if you want those signed bucket parameters to be the same for all the clients, or use signing and extra work on the CloudFront side.  Ideally, CloudFront is left 'dumb' to proxy and cache so that way you don't have vendor lock-in.  You may want to use other CDNs (read, cheaper) in the future.  The exact answer depends on what you're trying to protect and why.

The stream I linked to isn’t mine it just a test. My bucket isn’t public, and I have set cloudfront to use a signed url / cookies. The main thing is I need to prevent anyone being able to watch any of the videos unless they are logged in on my site
